# vTiger - Cannot select Custom module records from a Leads Module under More Information tab

Tags: php, vtiger

I have create a custom module **Chat** and when am trying to select Chat records from a **Leads** Module under the More Information tab.

It gives me error `"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in include\utils\ListViewUtils.php on line 1280"` and also its not listing any chats records but its working fine for other vtiger default module

Here is my code to set a Related List

```
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');

$accounts=Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Leads');
$accounts->setRelatedList(Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Chat'), 'Chat',Array('ADD','SELECT'));
```

Please help for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't include the code the error is pointing to. There is no `foreach` in your code. You probably are iterating an empty variable.

Comment: Have you created a function to select chat records from the database. And that function must be placed in module.php(chat.php) file.

Comment: @Milan : I have copied files from vtlib/ModuleDir/5.4.0  to the chat folder and replace the payslip with chat in chat.php only and have not created any other function.

Comment: Yes. You have to Create a function in Lead.php in Lead module such as get_campaigns function(check this function in Modules/Account/Account.php at line no 124 near about) which will select a record for chat module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Create a function as a told in Comment and your code is wrong for set relation between to module. You have to use this code.

```
 $module = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Store');
 $storemodule1 = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Calendar');
 $relationLabel = 'Activities';
 $function_name = 'get_activities';
 $module->setRelatedList( $storemodule1, $relationLabel, Array('ADD','SELECT'), $function_name );
```

The function which you will create replace it with 'get_activities' and i think you know which other value have to change.

Comment: Thank u Milan for help